# How a RT process can release the CPU for CFS processes, and get it back when there are no ready CFS processes

Tags: linux, scheduler, cfs

A question about scheduling in **Linux**:

- I have several processes scheduled with **CFS** and one process "`A`"
  that is running with `Real-Time (RT)` (SCHED_FIFO) scheduling - all process are
  bind to one specific CPU core.
- The process "`A`" is running on **RT** (SCHED_FIFO) because it should never be
  preempted for the other **CFS** processes.
- Instead, process "`A`" will release the CPU voluntarily when it
  decides, and let the other processes (scheduled with **CFS**) to
  utilize the CPU.

**Now the question:**

- How can process "`A`" release the CPU and let the other **CFS** processes
  that are ready to run, to take the CPU?
- If "A" changes its policy to **CFS** (SCHED_OTHER), then the **Linux scheduler** will potentially let it also run.
- Also if "`A`" changes its policy to **IDLE**, still the scheduler may let
  it run.

I want process "`A`" to get the CPU back when:

- There are no other **CFS** processes that are ready to run, OR  a
  predefined time (`e.g. 10ms`) is passed - whichever happens first.
- The second condition can be achieved by another process (running on
  ther CPU core) that will change "`A`" policy back to **RT**.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

> More specifically, how to guarantee that only the other ready **CFS**
>   processes will run, and not "`A`", until one of the mentioned
>   conditions is met?

Thanks!

Comment: @KamilCuk, with 'sched_setscheduler' or 'pthread_setschedparam'. sorry I accidently deleted your comment asking how I set the process "A" to Real-Time.

Comment: Can you post a full invokation  of these function? I don't understand, really, the default CFS doesn't "guarantee" cpu time on specific processor (well, according to my limited knowledge). Did you patch the kernel? What is your `uname -a`? Are you using some default kernel config? Realtime, it's just a priority, niceness below -20. It doesn't "guarantee" the cpu, how did you achieve that? So did you use `SCHED_FIFO`? `SCHED_RR`? `SCHED_DEADLINE`? What priority? How did you configure that? So maybe, from the other side, what does `chrt -v -p $pid_of_your_process` shows?

Comment: @KamilCuk, The process "A" is set to SCHED_FIFO (while all others are SCHED_OTHER which is the CFS). Therefore, "A" will get the CPU and never be preempted for the CFS processes (except for the guarantee percentage, as defined by sched_rt_runtime_us). All processes including A are bind to a specific CPU core.